# Can I use #12 ground wire as jumper when the other wire in the box is #14?

Tags: electrical, grounding, wire

If everything is wired with 14 gauge romex on a 15 amp breaker, can I use 12 gauge ground as a jumper inside a box?  This would be to either ground the box itself or as jumper between to outlets.

Comment: Jumper for ground.  I assumed since I specified ground wire that it was clear it's for carrying ground between outlets.  And yes, I am using bare wire.

Comment: Just making sure! There have been some wacky questions at times where people think "anything can be used for anything" - which is sometimes true - you can strip a regular wire and use it for ground or (under at least some cases) wrap a wire with another color of tape end-to-end to change the status. End result is: the wire is fine, the Answers are correct. I'll delete my comment after you read it (which I'll know if you delete your comment).

Comment: yeah - it took me sec for that to sink in but I can appreciate you wanting to make sure.  Actually I think you should leave the comments for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can always use larger gauge wire than for what the circuit is protected.  One limitation may be making sure you don't try to cram more/larger wires into the box than what it's capacity is.

Answer (score 1):

You can always go larger but not smaller. If you're using it to jump between two outlets, don't use the backstabs, pigtails are a better way. Grounding the box, green or bare.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but would you mind elaborating on the benefit of pigtails vs backstabs?  Thanks for your input

Comment: @billynoah the backstabs are spring loaded clamps accessed  by holes in the back of the outlet. Wires are stripped and inserted in the holes. The resulting connection is inferior  to the wire being hooked around the screw and then tightening the screw. The backstabs have been known to cause many house fires.   Any alternative to using backstabs is the better way.

Comment: Is that the same as a back wired receptacle where you tighten the screw to clamp the wires? This is the kind I'm using: https://inspectapedia.com/electric/Receptacle_Connectors_Clamp_Screw_028_DJFs.jpg

Comment: @billynoah  Not the same.  You have a back clamp screw outlet and those are great.  The backstabs  have just a small round hole that you shove the wire into, no screws to tighten.  The outlets also have screw terminals which are OK to use.